# problem password_reset_key_message.txt` - dj-rest-auth

Tags: python, api, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I'm creating a project (an api), but I'm stuck on the next part.
When sending the password reset mail, specifically `password_reset_key_message.txt`, I can't capture the user's 'key' and 'uid', I want to change the address.

Email delivery work fine, my problem is with `password_reset_key_message.txt`.

Packages

```
django==4.0.7
dj-rest-auth==2.2.5
django-allauth==0.51.0
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
{% extends "account/email/base_message.txt" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}{% autoescape off %}{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this e-mail because you or someone else has requested a password for your user account.
It can be safely ignored if you did not request a password reset. Click the link below to reset your password.{% endblocktrans %}

---

https://fontend-project.com/password-reset?id={{ uid }}&key={{ key }}

---

{% if username %}

{% blocktrans %}In case you forgot, your username is {{ username }}.{% endblocktrans %}{% endif %}{% endautoescape %}{% endblock %}
```

But i can't capture 'uid and key.

By default it uses '{{ password_reset_url }}', but I want to change the address, I need 'uid' and 'key' which are provided in '{{ password_reset_url }}' and I can't capture them, which I can do in the template o message file 'email_confirmation_message.txt'.

Help please, I have tried and could not find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I did the following:

1. In the `settings.py` of the main project, add a custom_password_serializer:

config/settings.py

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
     'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'myapp.serializers.CustomPasswordResetSerializer'
}
```

2. Create the custom_password_serializer:

config/serializers.py

```
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer
from myapp.forms import CustomResetForm

class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
     """
     Serializer for requesting a password reset e-mail.
     """
     @property
     def password_reset_form_class(self):
         return CustomResetForm
```

3. Add new `forms.py`

config/forms.py

```
from dj_rest_auth.forms import AllAuthPasswordResetForm
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from allauth.account.forms import default_token_generator
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import user_pk_to_url_str

class CustomResetForm(AllAuthPasswordResetForm):

     def save(self, request, **kwargs):
         current_site = get_current_site(request)
         email = self.cleaned_data['email']
         token_generator = kwargs.get('token_generator', default_token_generator)

         for user in self.users:

             temp_key = token_generator.make_token(user)
             uid = user_pk_to_url_str(user)

             context = {
                 'current_site': current_site,
                 'user': user,
                 'key': temp_key,
                 'uid': uid,
             }
             get_adapter(request).send_mail(
                 'account/email/password_reset_key', email, context
             )
         return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

4. Now you can capture user, key, uid in the `password_reset_key_message.txt` file

Remember that `password_reset_key_message.txt` must go in the following path `backend_directory/api/templates/account/email/`

Thanks to **[StephenSorriaux](https://github.com/StephenSorriaux)** for this solution, **[Source](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/427#issuecomment-1255664561)**.

I hope this solution helps.